# go: using pointer allows changing the contents of a struct. Why?

Tags: pointers, go

Consider the following example. I don't fully understand what happens "in the background" and seek an explanation. This version seems to make a copy of the struct `Foo` when I call `AddToEntry` from the main function. Right? How can I "proof" this in the code?

When go makes a copy of the struct, I am just manipulating the copy of the struct and when I get back to the `main` function I see the original as before?

When I expect a pointer (see comment in the code), everything is fine, my struct is not copied. How can avoid this kind of "error"? How can I make sure I am not copying the struct? Is there a possible compile time/run time check for that, or do I have be careful?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Entry []string
}

func MakeFoo() Foo {
    a:=Foo{}
    a.Entry = append(a.Entry,"first")
    return a
}

// if I change (f Foo) to (f *Foo), I get 
// the "desired" result
func (f Foo) AddToEntry() {
    f.Entry = append(f.Entry,"second")
}


func main() {
    f:=MakeFoo()
    fmt.Println(f) // {[first]}
    f.AddToEntry()
    fmt.Println(f) // {[first]}
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your great answers! Hard to choose which one I accept.

Comment: For future visitors: it helped me printing the current address with `fmt.Printf("%p\n",&MyObject)` to see when an object is copied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method signature is `func (f Foo) AddToEntry()`. The way methods work, `f.AddToEntry()` is is the same as:

```
g := Foo.AddToEntry
g(f)
```

The receiver is just another parameter. Why is this important? What happens when you pass a struct and modify it in a function? In C, Go, and other pass by value languages, the struct given in the parameter is only a copy. Therefore, you can not modify the original. Only return the new struct.

When you define `func (f *Foo) AddToEntry()`, you are defining the receiver, the first parameter, as a pointer. Obviously, given a pointer, you can modify the original struct. What is hidden is that you are implicitly referencing when you access a struct in Go. To put it another way, `(*ptrFoo).Entry` is the same as `ptrFoo.Entry` in Go.

So the issue here is that for those unaccustomed to go, the syntax is hiding some of what is going on. In C, you would never be able to edit a struct unless you passed a pointer to it. The same happens in Go. You need to use a pointer receiver in order to modify what you are receiving.

Answer (score 5):

Have you read this Go documentation?

[Should I define methods on values or pointers?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

[Methods: Pointers vs. Values](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I should read more (and think about it).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make sure I am not copying the struct? Is there a possible
>   compile time/run time check for that, or do I have be careful?

The short answer here is that **no** , you can't do a compile-time or run-time(1) check
for this - you just have to be careful. Once you get a bit familiar with go, this becomes natural.

(1) 
<sub><sup>Technically your function could query whether the type is a pointer or not with the [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements), but if you remember to do that, you'll also remember to make the parameter a pointer.</sup></sub>